# Question about WarpMode enum

Tags: c#, enums, conflict

There is tow enum by name "WarpMode" in System.Drawing.Drawing2D namespace

the first include : 
Title , TitleFlipX , TitleFlipY , TitleFlipXY , Clamp

and the second by include : 
Perspective , Bilinear

We can't define tow enums in th same namespace by the same name ..!! why here we can ?? !!

and How can I tell VS which enum of them I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is `WrapMode` and the second is `WarpMode`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, one is named [`WrapMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.wrapmode), and the other, [`WarpMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.warpmode). Note the transposed 'r' and 'a'.